# Can I apply for a French long-stay visa in France?

Tags: visa, student-visa

I am an American student who will be studying abroad in Paris. I am studying in France for 1 month this summer (July 3 to August 13) and then returning August 24 to stay for the year. I obviously will not need a visa for my 1-month stay, which is good, because Campus France is still processing my application. Unfortunately, my Campus France application won't be processed until mid July, at which point I will be in France. Since visas take 2-3 weeks to process, I won't have enough time to get my visa back in the States.

All that being explained, will it be possible to make a visa appointment in Paris? If not, does anyone have any suggestions for what to do?

Comment: Visas can not be applied for in-country. The visa section of the consulate where you applied handles the face-to-face side of your application. You will have to be there when [if] the application is granted.

Comment: @dda but some Schengen countries allow (at least some) people who are in the country to apply for a residence permit directly instead of making them leave the country to apply for a visa.  For example, US citizens can do that in Germany and in the Netherlands.  Can it be done in France?